# Convert array of JSON object to array only with values

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to convert array of JSON objects to an array only with values. I will really appreciate your help.Thank you.
here is my code

```
[
{
"Code": "1",
"Name": "MAN 1",
"DOB": "2020-01-01",
"age": 11,
"weight": 70
},
{
"Code": "2",
"Name": "MAN 2",
"DOB": "2020-01-02",
"age": 22,
"weight": 80
},
{
"Code": "3",
"Name": "MAN 3",
"DOB": "2020-01-03",
"age": 33,
"weight": 90
}
]
```

My Expected answer is:

```
[
['1','MAN 1','2020-01-01','11','70'],
['2','MAN 2','2020-01-02','22','80'],
['3','MAN 3','2020-01-03','33','90'],
]
```

How do i put a loop to achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want 2D array ?

Comment: and where's the code you have tried to achieve the output ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: When giving it a go, you'll probably want to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Comment: There's no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is always a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for this like:

```js
const data = [{Code:"1",Name:"MAN 1",DOB:"2020-01-01",age:11,weight:70},{Code:"2",Name:"MAN 2",DOB:"2020-01-02",age:22,weight:80},{Code:"3",Name:"MAN 3",DOB:"2020-01-03",age:33,weight:90}];

const res = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj))
console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure the wanted properties and use them in the wanted order as values for mapping the array.

```js
var data = [{ Code: "1", Name: "MAN 1", DOB: "2020-01-01", age: 11, weight: 70 }, { Code: "2", Name: "MAN 2", DOB: "2020-01-02", age: 22, weight: 80 }, { Code: "3", Name: "MAN 3", DOB: "2020-01-03", age: 33, weight: 90 }],
    result = data.map(({ Code, Name, DOB, age, weight }) => [Code, Name, DOB, age, weight]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` method:

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "Code": "1",
    "Name": "MAN 1",
    "DOB": "2020-01-01",
    "age": 11,
    "weight": 70
  },
  {
    "Code": "2",
    "Name": "MAN 2",
    "DOB": "2020-01-02",
    "age": 22,
    "weight": 80
  },
  {
    "Code": "3",
    "Name": "MAN 3",
    "DOB": "2020-01-03",
    "age": 33,
    "weight": 90
  }
];

var arr = obj.reduce((p, c) => {
  p.push([c.Code, c.Name, c.DOB, c.age,c.weight]);
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You *can*, but it's really not the right tool for the job. (Indeed, I'm with [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) and [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224): It's almost *never* the right tool for the job.)